# Does an equivalent of jackson-datatype-hibernate for jersey-media-moxy exist?

Tags: json, hibernate, jersey, jackson, moxy

As the title suggests, I'm looking for an equivalent of [jackson-datatype-hibernate](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-hibernate) that works with [jersey-media-moxy](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/media/moxy) as it is the preferred implementation for xml/json marshaling for Jersey. Specifically, I need the functionality provided by that library to automatically handle uninitialized Hibernate collections (associations and collections with fetch=lazy).

If you don't know of an equivalent library, any alternative suggestions would be welcome. However, one alternative I've seen that I do not wish to pursue is adding Hibernate.isInitialzed() calls to all of my get methods.

Thanks in advance.